# RHEL Serial TTY

Tags: tty

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Technical_Notes/deployment.html

According to this, /etc/inittab has been deprecated.
As suggested from this I created a /etc/init/serial-ttyS2.conf.
After that I has to make the service start with the following command:

> [root@sbc-l1c-pcc-00 ~]# initctl start serial-ttyS2
>
> [root@sbc-l1c-pcc-00 ~]# ps aux | grep tty
>
> root      7779  0.0  0.0   2016   536 ttyS2    Ss+  13:38   0:00 /sbin/agetty/dev/ttyS2 9600 vt100

However when I try to connect no login prompt pop out, just a blank screen.
I tried to restarted the serial-ttyS2 while the screen was still open and the login screen came out. And I have to do it every time I need to to connect.
Does somebody have a clue why?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the missing space `/sbin/agetty/dev/ttyS2` is not real, otherwise you have serious issues.

It's likely that you haven't asked agetty to monitor Data Carrier Detect. When asserted DCD means that there is a session in progress. DCD in turn requires DTR to be present, as Data Terminal Ready when asserted means that the other RS-232 lines from the terminal are not invalid.

Because of the lack of knowledge of the DCD (ie: user at terminal) status agetty doesn't know when a user connects, and thus can't present a prompt. Instead it waits for the user to press Return -- see the description of the `-L` option in `man agetty` for more information on this point.

Assuming you've got a correctly-cabled null-modem cable:

```
/sbin/agetty --8bits --flow-control -L=never ttyS0 9600
```

Otherwise you'll just have to live with people pressing Return.

You might find some hints in this [blog post](http://vk5tu.livejournal.com/49020.html) about serial terminals and Fedora 20.

Comment: Hello,

Thank for the answer and before investigating more I would like to understand what you mean with the first sentence 

 "Assuming that the missing space /sbin/agetty/dev/ttyS2 is not real, otherwise you have serious issues".

Comment: It should be /sbin/agetty  /dev/ttyS2

Comment: I see your point, sorry the output got all stuck together.
Anyway it works, Simply I don't know why the first few times it wasn't answering to any keyboard input, until it did and instead of reloading the service I just have to press any key.
Thank anyway